# Designing html elements in lazyload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lazy-loading

All the samples shown for [Lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) have pre-determined number of elements to be displayed using [lazyload](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload#demos), please see [here](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload/blob/master/demos/with_srcset_sizes.html).

Say if I don't know the number of elements beforehand, how to design at `html` side to implement in `Lazyload`.

More precizely, I have a gridview as shown in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Thomas_nyan/dea7qfth/1/). That fiddle sample has eight `<li> html elements`.

I am working to load all data using Lazyload with horizontal scrolling.
Say if the data is fed from a database at server using `Json` without knowing the number of grid elements beforehand, how can prepare at html side?

For example, this fiddle has predefined 2 x 4 grid elements. But if 2 x N is the status till I receive Json from server. Then I know exactly what is N value after receiving the Json, may be 2 x 50 or 2 x 100 or 2 x 10000.

For that case, how can I implement in html side so that I can load all images using Lazyload and horizontal scrolling?

Comment: I research around and found that , according to this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258880/changing-css-content-property-dynamically), I can change CSS content dynamically. So I use AJAX to query the size of images and returned with Json. Then according to the size, I can change the CSS content dynamically and refresh the page. I think I can do that way.

Comment: Will update if successfully implemented.